# Melpa packages not listed

Tags: init-file, package, package-repositories, install

On Mac OS, Emacs 28.2, I have the following lines at the top of my `init.el`

```
(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
  '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/")
  '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))

(unless package-archive-contents
  (package-refresh-contents))

(package-initialize)
```

But when I run `M-x package-list-packages`, I don't see any package from MELPA. Under the column "Archive", I only see `gnu` or `nongnu`. Running `M-x package-refresh-contents` doesn't help. I get no error at startup and the file `emacs.d/elpa/archives/melpa/archive-contents` exists.

I am trying to install some MELPA packages like quelpa, but something seems broken. What is the fix?

Comment: As @shynur points out in the answer, you are using `add-to-list` incorrectly. Do `C-h f add-to-list` to read its doc string: that would alert you to the fact that you can only use it to add one element at a time. Emacs provides documentation at your fingertips, but you have to learn how to use that facility. Do `C-h C-h` and explore!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the official website of MELPA](https://melpa.org/#/getting-started):

```lisp
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
  '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
```

Did you notice that it uses HTTPS?

---

Also, see `add-to-list`:

> `(add-to-list LIST-VAR ELEMENT &optional APPEND COMPARE-FN)`

You're using the wrong invocation.

---

Add these repositories separately:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
  '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
  '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
```

---

@vpk: please see here:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works! But I still don't see `quelpa` in the list of packages. Not sure why?

Comment: @vpk: Repositories *GNU* and *NonGNU* go with Emacs distribution; others do not. So you need to add them **manually** (just like how you add *Org* and *MELPA*). If you want to use *quelpa*, you should take a look at its official website and see what URL it provides.

Comment: The reason I'm expecting to see `quelpa` is because quelpa's documentation states that it is provided by `melpa`, see here https://github.com/quelpa/quelpa#installation

Comment: @vpk: It seems that *quelpa* is a package which can be downloaded at *MELPA*, not a repository.  See my updated answer (wait for a minute).

Comment: yes, i edited the question to clarify that `quelpa` is a package. I can see tons of melpa-provided packages including `quelpa-leaf` and `quelpa-use-package`, but I don't see `quelpa` like you do in your screenshot. I'm referring to the `M-x package-list-packages` buffer.

Comment: I figured out `quelpa` was already installed, and it was listed towards the bottom of the `M-x package-list-packages` buffer, below the list of uninstalled packages.